# Как загрузить 4К видео файл на yoututbe используя API?

Tags: youtube-api

После загрузки 4k видео файла при помощи API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-video-api), он размещается на youtube с максимальным разрешением HD

Когда я загружаю тот же самый видео файл интерактивно, то он после некоторого времени доступен на youtube с качеством 4k.

Возможно ли загрузить видео файл 4k на youtube при помощи API и какие параметры для этого необходимо задать?

Comment: Не смотрели в официальной документации API по этому пункту?

Comment: Не нашел в официальной документации API возможности при загрузке видео указать в каких форматах его загружать.